# VB.NET DataGrid Column Binding

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview, datasource

Trying to figure out how to setup the mappingname for a vb.net datagrid control for an XML sub node. The datasource is established using...

VB.NET Code Establishing DataSource

```
dim ds as new DataSet()
ds.ReadXML(New System.IO.StringReader(xmlString))
DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
DataGridView1.DataMember = "task"
```

And I can map most of the nodes in the below XML string as long as they are right below the task node, however can't find a way to map `client > clientname` to a column.

Also needing to figure out how to programatically remove any rows from the datasource if the node `org > orgname` doesn't match `company name` and `substatus > substatus` doesn't match `not started` or `in progress`.

XML String

```
<imsapi>
<status>0</status>
<statusmessage>Login OK</statusmessage>
<zoneresponse>
<tasks>
    <task>
        <contact>
            <surname>Last Name</surname>
            <givennames>First Name</givennames>
            <userid>JScqTyVQXFwgCg==</userid>
        </contact>
        <contactname>User Name</contactname>
        <org>
            <orgid>JScqTyVRXFQgCg==</orgid>
            <orgname>Business Unit Name</orgname>
        </org>
        <requestdatetime>2019/06/26 08:56:09</requestdatetime>
        <status>Not Started</status>
        <readtaskdatetime>2019/07/04 12:44:08</readtaskdatetime>
        <description>Job description goes here...</description>
        <custon>INTERNAL</custon>
        <duedate>2020/01/13</duedate>
        <lastupdated>2020/01/06</lastupdated>
        <jobnumber>2387</jobnumber>
        <duedatetime>2020/01/13 00:00:00</duedatetime>
        <client>
            <clientid>JScqTyVRXFQgCg==</clientid>
            <clientname>Client Name</clientname>
        </client>
        <taskname>Job Name</taskname>
        <taskid>JiYqUyVRPEslCg==</taskid>
        <lastupdateddatetime>2020/01/06 10:39:44</lastupdateddatetime>
        <requestdate>2019/06/26</requestdate>
        <tasktype>Manufacturing Order</tasktype>
        <substatus>
            <substatusid>IyZaVywK</substatusid>
            <substatus>Not Started</substatus>
        </substatus>
    </task>
  </tasks>
</zoneresponse>
```

I have tried using `.`, `/`, and `\` to try to map to the sub node but non of these have produced a map.

Comment: ReadXml Method will not work.  Once you get past 4 levels of tags the dataset becomes fragmented and cannot be put back together.  It is best you try doing this with Xml Linq (XDocument).  I can help but need to know where is the Company Name?

Comment: The company name is at `task > org > orgname` and the substatus is at `task > substatus > substatus` Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little complicated because there are two nested tags "substatus".

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim xml As String = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME)
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)


        Dim business As String = "Business Unit Name"
        Dim removeTypes() As String = {"Not Started", "In Progress"}

        Dim removeItem As List(Of XElement) = doc.Descendants("task") _
                                        .Where(Function(x) (CType(x.Descendants("orgname").FirstOrDefault(), String) <> business) Or (Not x.Descendants("substatus").Any(Function(y) removeTypes.Contains(CType(y, String))))) _
                                        .ToList()

        For i = removeItem.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            removeItem(i).Remove()
        Next i


    End Sub

End Module
```